# Определить подотрезок, в который попала случайная точка на отрезке от 0 до 1

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть отрезок от 0 до 1, разбитый на подотрезки, таким образом, что первый [0;а<sub>1</sub>], второй
[а<sub>1</sub>; а<sub>1</sub>+а<sub>2</sub>], третий [а<sub>1</sub>+а<sub>2</sub>; а<sub>1</sub>+а<sub>2</sub>+а<sub>3</sub>] последний из них - это 
[а<sub>1</sub>+а<sub>2</sub>+...+а<sub>(n-1)</sub>; 1], где а<sub>1</sub>...а<sub>n-1</sub> - вещественные
и случайно выбирается вещественная точка, из этого же отрезка, от 0 до 1, и надо определить подотрезок, в который попала точка.
Допустим, эти подотрезки можно представить в виде списка, но как определить попадание случайной точки?

Comment: точка внутри, если больше начала и меньше конца

Comment: идем последовательно по списку a1,a2 и вычитаем их с положения точки. Как только стало отрицательно - проскочили правую границу. Отдельно нужно ещё обработать ноль (тогда на границе).

Comment: Ну переберите все отрезки, а дальше как написал @Grundy. Если хотите покруче, составьте список из точек (0, a1, a1+a2, ..., 1), и найдите в нём вашу случайную точку бинарным поиском. (`std::lower_bound` и всё такое).

Comment: @Grundy, где-то не хватает равенства...

Comment: +1 за коммент VladD. Сначала частичные суммы, потом бин поиск.

Comment: Сортируем начала отрезков по возрастанию. Потом бинарным поиском находим точку, которая равна искомой либо первую, самую большую из меньших данной. Ответ будет - конец этого отрезка больше, чем данная точка или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас значения a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n-1</sub> представлены в виде, скажем, массива

```
double a[];
```

то просто выполняете цикл:

```
double a[] = { 0, // a[0] не используем
            0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1 };

int idx(double x)
{
    if (x < 0 || x > 1) return -1;        // ЋиЁЎЄ 
    double end = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
        if (x <= (end+=a[i])) return i;
    return sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
}


int main()
{
    cout << idx(0.01) << endl;
    cout << idx(0.21) << endl;
    cout << idx(0.41) << endl;
    cout << idx(0.65) << endl;
    cout << idx(0.71) << endl;
    cout << idx(0.91) << endl;
}
```

Примерно так.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, вы сохранили все эти интервалы в `double list[]`, а длину в `int N`.
Тогда:

```
int detect(double point) {
    double sum = list[0];
    if (point < sum) return -1; // точка ушла влево от всех
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
                      // правая точка текущего отрезка
      sum += list[i]; // равна правой точке предыдущего + i-тый интервал из списка
      // левый край отрезка проверять не нужно, так как point заведомо больше(или равно) - иначе бы мы уже закончили поиск
      if (point < sum) return i;  
    }
    return -2; // точка ушла вправо от всех
}
```

Если учитывать, что крайние точки `0, 1` вы не храните в списке:

```
// всего отрезков N+1: [0, a1), [a1, a1+a2), .. [sum, sum+an), [sum+an, 1)
int detect(double point) {
    double sum = 0;
    if (point < sum) return -1; // точка < 0
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      sum += list[i];
      if (point < sum) return i;  
    }
    if (point < 1) return N; // Возможно, можно сравнивать <=
    return -2; // точка >/>= 1
}
```

---

Для асимптотики, лучшей, чем `O(n)` нужно отделить операцию ввода данных (которая не может быть лучше `O(n)`) вместе с нахождением частичных сумм.
После этого можно применять метод дихотомии `O(log(n))`.

Это может иметь смысл, если необходимо тестировать множество случайных точек на одних и тех же отрезках.

Comment: sum += list[i];
      if (point < sum) return i;

Comment: Что происходит? Я не совсем понял

Comment: мы находим текущую точку. `a0+a1+a2+...+a(i-1)` (предыдущая точка) у нас уже есть, прибавляем a(i), чтобы найти текущую точку(правую точку текущего отрезка)